# Blinking effect while plotting pointAnnotation

Tags: swift, swiftui, mapbox-ios

I am using mapbox to plot a marker other than the user(own). I am using mapbox for this. I am using following code to plot the annotation.

```
        private func plotNearbyDevices() {
            guard mapView != nil else { return }
            let annotationMgr = mapView.annotations.makePointAnnotationManager(id: "annotationLayer")
            var markers: [PointAnnotation] = []
            for device in devices {
                if var marker = currentMarkers.first(where: { $0.id == device.id.uuidString }) {
                    let deviceCoordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: device.lattitude, longitude: device.longitude)
                    marker.point.coordinates = deviceCoordinate
                    markers.append(marker)
                } else {
                    let markerImage = UIImage(named: "ic_circle")
                    let deviceCoordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: device.lattitude, longitude: device.longitude)
                    var pointAnnotation = PointAnnotation(id: device.id.uuidString, coordinate: deviceCoordinate)
                    pointAnnotation.image = .init(image: markerImage!, name: "\(device.id.uuidString)")
                    pointAnnotation.iconAnchor = .bottom
                    markers.append(pointAnnotation)
                }
            }
            currentMarkers = markers
            annotationMgr.annotations = currentMarkers
        }
```

Main issue here is in this section

```
     let deviceCoordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: device.lattitude, longitude: device.longitude)
                    marker.point.coordinates = deviceCoordinate
                    markers.append(marker)
```

As the mapbox does not enable us to directly modify the coordinate for the point annotation, we require to remove and add the annotation which causes the marker to blink.

I am using mapbox package from this location: https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-maps-ios.git version: 10.12.2

I would like to remove this blinking effect. Any help or suggestion is much appreciated. If required a sample project can be accessed from this git repo:
[Sample app link](https://github.com/SarojMaharjan/MapboxMarkerCheck.git)